# How do I transform a dictionary of dataframe to a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have a dictionary with multiple keys that contain has a value a Data Frame which looks like below and can have different number of indices.

```
'key1':

            colB
    colA   
    str1       3
    str2       4
    str3       5

'key2':

            colB
    colA   
    str2       3
    str3       4
    str5       5

'key3':

            colB
    colA   
    str4       3
    str5       4
    str6       5
```

I would like to know how to create a Data Frame that looks like

```
        str1   str2   str3  ...   str 6
key1     3       4      5    ..    NaN
key2    NaN      3      4    ..    NaN     
key3    NaN     NaN    NaN   ..     5
```

with 'NaN' when a value is missing.

I already done it by using reset_index, creating pandas series for each data frame and then looking for the matching values per rows to recreate the right Data Frame but I find it very slow and not optimal at all.

Comment: Remove the 'csv' from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need just `concat` and `unstack` notice `d` is your `dict`

```
pd.concat(d).colB.unstack()
Out[663]: 
colA  str1  str2  str3  str4  str5  str6
k1     3.0   4.0   5.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
k2     NaN   3.0   4.0   NaN   5.0   NaN
k3     NaN   NaN   NaN   3.0   4.0   5.0
```

Comment: How can I keep the same order on rows because the keys are getting sorted from A to Z?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `pandas.concat()`. See here for documentation [Concat Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)

For example Let's say your dictionary is called `my_dict` you could execute the following code:

```
pd.concat(my_dict.values())
```

This assumes you have already imported pandas as pd. See the documentation for options embedded in concat.

As a final note, to get it into the form you want, you could use:

```
pd.unstack()
```

to get the multiindex values as row headers. Or simply `pd.df.rename()`

To give you more advice here, it would be helpful to have the code to generate the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

See sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
key1 = {'str1':3,'str2':4,'str3':5}
key2 = {'str2':3,'str3':4,'str5':5}
key3 = {'str4':3,'str5':4,'str6':5}

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(key1, orient='index')
df1.rename(columns={0:'key1'},inplace=True)
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(key2, orient='index')
df2.rename(columns={0:'key2'},inplace=True)
df3=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(key3, orient='index')
df3.rename(columns={0:'key3'},inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
df_final=df.T
df_final.head()
```

code is pretty simple, please let me know if you need more explanation.